# How to Read Type Signatures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like understand how the type signature works, in other words: I am baffled by the output I get from `:type`.

```
 :type (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Why is it not

```
 :type (+)
(+) :: (Number, Number) -> Number
```

instead?

I understand that

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

can be rewritten as

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)
```

which means that `(+)` takes an argument `a` and outputs a function with type `a ->a`. Why does it output a function and not a number?

Comment: Why should `(+5)` be a number?  What number should it be?

Comment: Do you understand currying and how it relates to your quesetion?

Comment: There is no type `Number`. The type `Num a => a -> a -> a` is more general than something like `Int -> Int -> Int`, but less general than `a -> a -> a`. Essentially, `(+)` is defined for some, but not all, types.

Comment: Currying - Is that how you make a curry? I looked it up and it is intuitive, i just didn't know that that is the notation used for Haskell type signatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(+)` function is used as a *binary operator*. Indeed: if you write:

```
5 + 2
```

you have, behind the curtains, written:

```
(+) 5 2
```

So you call the function with `5` and `2` as arguments. Now in Haskell every function takes exactly *one* argument as input. So `(+) 5 2` is actually a compact notation of:

```
((+) 5) 2
```

Indeed, we first takes `5` as argument for the `(+)` function, and this will produce a *new* function that takes as input a number and returns a number such that the outcome is five plus that number.

We can thus define a function:

```
f5 = (+) 5
```

and then apply `f5` to for example `3` and `7`, and we will get `f5 3 = 8` and `f5 7 = 12`. So if we analyze the types, we will see that:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)
(+) 5 :: Num a => a -> a
((+) 5) 2 :: Num a => a
```

So now we can answer your question:

> Why does it output a function and not a number?

If it would immediately output a number, then we could only give it a single number, so in that case we would have written `(+) 5` and immediately obtain a number. The only logical way to do that would be to return `5` and thus let `(+)` act as a *unary operator* (an operator that takes one parameter into account). But in Haskell, the `(+)` is a binary operator.

> Why is it not
>
> ```
> :type (+)
> (+) :: (Number, Number) -> Number
> ```

Haskell has a notion of tuples. But again that tuple is a *single* argument. In case we would construct such function, we would call it with:

```
f (2, 3)
```

If `f = (+)`, then `f (2, 3)` would result in `5`. But it is not very flexible. A frequent pattern in functional programming is taking a function, and apply a limited number of arguments on it (like we did with `f5 = (+) 5` and then pass that function as an argument again. By using tuples, we lose that flexibility.

Since some functions work with tuples, there are two popular functions called [**`curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry) and [**`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry). These functions can transform a given function that takes a tuple as input into a function with two arguments, and vice versa.

For example:

```
Prelude> :t uncurry (+)
uncurry (+) :: Num c => (c, c) -> c
```

So by constructing `uncurry (+)` we have constructed a function that takes as input a 2-tuple.

Note that `curry` and `uncurry` work only with 2-tuples (and thus two arguments). There are variants that work with more arguments, but these are not that popular.

Usually using the approach of functions constructing more specialized functions allows more flexibility and thus are more useful.

Say for instance I had an `uncurry` version of `(+)`:

```
uplus :: Num c => (c, c) -> c
uplus = uncurry (+)
```

Then how would I construct a partially applied function `f5 :: Num c => c -> c` with that? I could write it like:

```
f5 :: Num c => c -> c
f5 x = uplus (5, x)
```

but this requires a lot more syntax. Furthermore if I extend `uplus` to work with 3-tuples. I have to introduce more variables (`y`, `z`, etc.) to write the partially applied function.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it not
>
> ```
> :type (+)
> (+) :: (Number, Number) -> Number
> ```

I am assuming that with `Number` you mean any type in class `Num`.

This would make ti possible to add an `Integer` (numeric type) and a `Complex Double` (another numeric type) and get as a result a `Rational`.
We can't really do that.

We can only sum two values of the *same* numeric type, and obtain a result of the *same* type. We need to express that all these three numeric types are equal. This is done by the standard signature:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

If you instead consider `Number` as a single, specific, numeric type, then we could not add `Int`s, since that is a different type. We could remove all numeric types and use only `Number`, extending it to encompass complexes, rationals, integers, and all other numeric types. The programmer would then lose control of the underlying representation (making it hard to predict performance) and types would be much less precise: we can't guarantee that `length :: [a] -> Number` does not return a complex number, for instance...

Answer (score 1):

The two types for `(+)` you suggested are actually isomorphic (the same). To prove two things are isomorphic, we must show that there is a pair of invertible functions which go back and forth between the representations. These functions already exist in the standard library as `uncurry` and `curry`

```
> :t uncurry (+)
uncurry (+) :: Num a => (a, a) -> a

> let add (a, b) = a + b
> :t curry add
curry add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Proving that `curry/uncurry` are actually inverses of each other is an exercise for the reader.

To your second question "why does `(+)` take one argument and return a function rather than a number", this is called partial application. Calling `(+)` with a single argument returns a partially applied function that captures or "closes over" that argument. For example,

```
addOne :: Num a => a -> a
addOne = (1+)
```